# Refreshing page lost data of API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hi everyone i am getting data from api in react and also storing token in my local storage but when i refresh the page my data of API lost but my token remain save in local storage .
Now i don't want to lost my data on refresh my page

Comment: store it in localstorage like the token

Comment: You probably don't need to store the data localstorage.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve? What data do you want to keep despite a page refresh?

Comment: i want to get the userlist form Api

Answer (score 1):

You could store your data in your localstorage aswell. But I don't see why you couldn't just go fetch your data once again. The less you store Client side, the better. Because everything stored client side can be altered by the client.

P.S. [NegativeFriction](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8138367/negativefriction) Is having a great point on reading old data, in the comment.

Comment: Not to mention it's old data. Having a local cache is not inherently bad, but if someone is reading data from 20 minutes ago, it can easily be inaccurate and not suitable for the site's intended use.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the data (user list in your case) in the local storage, but I would discourage you from doing that for the following reasons:

1. Local storage is limited and adding a user list will pollute that space for you.
2. Data like user list might need updating regularly. It is recommended that you get a fresh list every time.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how complex your app is you can use a state manager like Redux or you can simply store the data you need by converting it to a string and storing it away. Once your application refreshes fetch this string again from local storage and load it back into your components.

```
let myData = JSON.stringify(data)
localStorage.setItem('profile_data')

//on page reload
let storedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile_data'))
```

Have to agree with @Nicolas on refetching your data on client apps. If its stuff like user profile you are storing then it would be wise to fetch that data every-time a page refreshes.